# Summing matrix columns within for loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop, matrix

I am writing the following function and for some reason, I cannot get the columns of the matrix to add within my for loop. They just keep repeating the initial vector.

```
TaylorSine <- function(x=seq(-2*pi, 2*pi, .01), k=1) {

 if (k %% 2 == 0){ a <- 0
 } else if ((-1)^floor(k/2) == -1){ 
      a <- 1
 } else if ((-1)^floor(k/2) == 1){ 
      a <- -1
 }

b <- matrix(nrow=length(x), ncol=k)
 for(i in 2:k){
 b[, 1] <- x
 ## for some reason a*(x^i)/factorial(i) is repeating x not adding the previous column b[, i-1] to b[, -1]????????
 b[, i] <- b[, i-1] + a*(x^i)/factorial(i)
 print(head(b))
 }
b[, k]
}
TaylorSine(k=4)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `if (k is even) a <- 0` so you are adding b[,i-1] + 0 over and over and over. try with k=3 and you'll see something different

Comment: Ahha. I have to embed the if statement within the for loop...

Comment: There has to be a better way. Describe the actual algorithm in a natural language.

Comment: `TaylorSine <- function(x=seq(-2*pi, 2*pi, .01), k=1) {  
     b <- matrix(nrow=length(x), ncol=k)
     
     for(i in 2:k){
           if (i %% 2 == 0){
                    a <- 0
               } else if ((-1)^floor(i/2) == -1){ 
                    a <- 1
               } else if ((-1)^floor(i/2) == 1){ 
                    a <- -1
          }
     b[, 1] <- x
     b[, i] <- b[, i-1] + a*(x^i)/factorial(i)
     }
b[, k]
}
TaylorSine(k=20)
`

Comment: taylor series approximation of a sine function

Comment: you could do `f <- function(x, n) {n <- 0:(n - 1) * 2 + 1; sum((x ** n) / factorial(n) * c(1, -1))}; f(5, 10); sin(5)`

Comment: A Taylor series is an approximation around a point. Are we being asked to make such an approximation around the point x=0? Or are we just trying to assemble a series of coefficients?

Comment: Yes bondeddust, I was attempting an approximation around point x=0.